# vb.net Find Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, find, focus

In the Windows, the native Notepad program has a find form. Basically When the user types and hits 'Find Next', the program proceeds to find the text while keeping the focus on the Find form. This way the user can keep hitting the 'Enter' key or the button and still have the text highlighted while the form is focused.

My problem is that I have a different form for the "Search" feature and whenever the user hits "Enter" the text is found and the focus is set on the TextBox but when the user hits "Enter" again, the text gets edited because of the focus.

Currently, I'm using Regex to do this and I am using a WPF TextBox using HostElement:

```
Private Function GetRegExpression() As Regex
    Dim result As Regex
    Dim regExString As [String]
    regExString = txtbx_Find.Text

    If matchCaseCheckBox.Checked Then
        result = New Regex(regExString)
    Else
        result = New Regex(regExString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End If
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub FindText()
    ''
    Dim WpfTest1 As New SpellPad.Tb
    Dim ElementHost1 As System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost = frm_Menu.Controls("ElementHost1")
    Dim TheTextBox As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox = CType(ElementHost1.Child, Tb).ctrl_TextBox
    ''
    If isFirstFind Then
        regex = GetRegExpression()
        match = regex.Match(TheTextBox.Text)
        isFirstFind = False
    Else
        match = regex.Match(TheTextBox.Text, match.Index + 1)
    End If
    If match.Success Then
        Dim row As Integer = TheTextBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(TheTextBox.CaretIndex)
        MoveCaretToLine(TheTextBox, row + 1)
        TheTextBox.SelectionStart = match.Index
        TheTextBox.SelectionLength = match.Length
        TheTextBox.Focus()
        Me.Focus()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show([String].Format("Cannot find ""{0}""   ", txtbx_Find.Text), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        isFirstFind = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btn_FindNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_FindNext.Click
    ''
    Dim WpfTest1 As New SpellPad.Tb
    Dim ElementHost1 As System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost = frm_Menu.Controls("ElementHost1")
    Dim TheTextBox As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox = CType(ElementHost1.Child, Tb).ctrl_TextBox
    ''
    FindText()
    'theTextBox.Focus()

End Sub
```

I want it to be just like Notepad where the user hits "Enter" and keeps focus on the Find Form while selecting the text. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should catch "keyup" event of your form like this :

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub Window_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        FindNext()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btn_FindNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_FindNext.Click
    FindText()
End Sub
Private Sub FindNext()
    ''
    Dim WpfTest1 As New SpellPad.Tb
    Dim ElementHost1 As System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost = frm_Menu.Controls("ElementHost1")
    Dim TheTextBox As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox = CType(ElementHost1.Child, Tb).ctrl_TextBox
    ''
    FindText()
    'theTextBox.Focus()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Also, you can copy and paste "If e.Key = Key.Enter Then...." to your KeyUp event of your textbox (textbox that holds the text to be searched)

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that worked. It still keeps focus on the TextBox and when I click `Enter` it doesn't activate the Find feature.

Comment: did you try your using KeyUp event of your TextBox? o_O if so, can you try using btn_FindNext.Focus() ? if you use Focus() method on another item your textbox's focus automatically will be lost. Remember, you should use btn_FindNext.Focus() in your FindNext() Sub. Let me know if it helped :)

Comment: Yea :/ I had it like that before. The problem is that when I hit the `Enter` button, my code has the focus code my ScrollToCarret fucntion which basically allows the user to keep scrolling through the words when it exceeds the window size so the user doesn't have to use the scroll bar to scroll. Regex doesn't have that feature where when it searches for string and it goes below the window, it wont scroll. I feel like the main problem is in the focus, I took out the focus and the find window keeps focus however because the .FOCUS isn't there i cant see the text selection.